# Update the column which has sequence number dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which has two column rID, SequenceNo values will be something like

Table name - Maintable

| rid | seqno |
| --- | --- |
| r1 | 1 |
| r2 | 2 |
| r3 | 3 |
| r4 | 4 |
| r5 | 5 |

Please note above is just an example there can N no of rows.

Now if we get a request like

```
r1 needs to have sequence no 5
r2 needs to have sequence no 4
r5 needs to have sequence no 2
```

So the request for update will be got as below,

```
**create table #apprevisedsequence
(
mid varchar(10),
appsequence int
)

insert into #apprevisedsequence
select r1,5
insert into #apprevisedsequence
select r2,4
insert into #apprevisedsequence
select r5,2


update a set a.seqno = b.Appsequence
from maintable a join
#apprevisedsequence b on a.rid = b.mid**
```

The above code will handle the required seqno for r1, r2 and r5. But we need to update r3 and r4 in a sequential way such that r3 is updated as 1 and r4 updated as 3 since that has the highest sequential order previously. Can anyone help me with script so that this can handle with even 10 rows or 20 rows and request can be 5 or 10 rows.

So my expected result set will be like

| rid | seqno |
| --- | --- |
| r3 | 1 |
| r5 | 2 |
| r4 | 3 |
| r2 | 4 |
| r1 | 5 |

We can update the request as received but not sure how we can update the remaining rows based on range

Comment: Sure, we can help you, but you need to explain where specifically are you stuck. What have you tried so far? Why isn't it working?

Comment: @ThomA Can you help? I couldn't. To me, the task is unclear and should be described more detailed. Sounds like an update command using `CASE` is required, but more sample input data and the expected results would make things much clearer.

Comment: As I stated, if they explain what specifically they need help with, sure, @JonasMetzler . They don't at the moment.

Comment: I can help, question is little unclear here "r1 needs to have sequence no 5 r2 needs to have sequence no 4 r5 needs to have sequence no 2" you want dynamicdally sequencing of rid and seqno where seqno will be updated in the way the r1 get the highest seqno value and rN get the lowest seqno value, right?

Comment: @prayagseth is right..

Comment: Prayag sheth one more thing to be noted is that it will have more number of rows as well. like may till r10 or r20 and so is the request to update. So this should be more like a dynamic script which handles any number of rows

Comment: What kind of data are you modelling? Do you have a list of things and two buttons with arrows Up and Down? So far you haven't described anything else than a normal `update t set seqno = seqnoNew from yourtable t where id = @requestID`

Comment: My expected result set is : r3 should be seq 1,  r5 should be seq 2, r4 should be seq 3 , r2 should be seq 4, r1 should be seq 5. 

Hope this makes you clear. Again am saying this is not limited to 5 rows it can be n number of rows and the query needs to be dynamically handling it.

Comment: I suggest adding that stuff in your question together with a table illustrating the concept

Comment: You haven't addressed my entire comment yet, @user2523084

Comment: should sequence values after all updates be unique per whatever

Comment: @ThomA updated again, if you cant understand more than this I am not sure how to explain further.. I have explained each and everything in detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a bit long winded but it works.

The idea is to get a list of fixed values (the 3 you know), then a list of RIDs with no fixed value and a list of seq numbers with no fixed value, assign each a row number an then join these to fill in the gaps.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (rid varchar(10), seqno int);
INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
('r1', 1),
('r2', 2),
('r3', 3),
('r4', 4),
('r5', 5);

DECLARE @fixed TABLE(rid varchar(10), seqno int);
INSERT INTO @fixed VALUES 
('r5', 2),
('r2', 4),
('r1', 5);

WITH SeqenceNos AS 
    (SELECT t.seqno, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.seqno) as RowN 
        FROM @t t 
        LEFT JOIN @fixed f on t.seqno = f.seqno 
        WHERE f.seqno is null)
, 
RIDs AS 
(SELECT t.rid, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.rid) as RowN 
    FROM @t t 
    LEFT JOIN @fixed f on t.rid = f.rid 
    WHERE f.rid is null)

UPDATE t 
    SET seqno = ISNULL(f.seqno, s.seqno)
    FROM @t t 
    LEFT JOIN @fixed f on t.rid = f.rid
    LEFT JOIN RIDs r on t.rid = r.rid
    LEFT JOIN SeqenceNos s on r.RowN = s.RowN;

SELECT * FROM @t;
```

Here's a fiddle of it in action

https://dbfiddle.uk/xMnR-QCE